# ¿Como puedo ejecutar un servicio en segundo plano sin que se detenga?

Tags: java, android

El problema que tengo, es que al lanzar el servicio en segundo plano al cabo de 5 min se detiene. También se detiene al **bloquear el teléfono** o al **cerrar la app** en vez de minimizarla.

Lo que quiero es lanzar el servicio y que este siga funcionando sin ser interrumpido.He mirado en mil paginas, pero no doy con la respuesta.
Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente estoy desarrollando algo similar, manteniendo un servicio vivo, a pesar de que la `App` este cerrada o se reinicie el `Smartphone`, lo primero que debes hacer es:

Crear una clase que extiende `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));

}
```

}

En el `servicio`:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

.....

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

.....
```

}

Luego vas a tu `AndroidManifest`, registras el `BroadcastReceiver` y el `servicio` en caso de que Android Studio no lo cree automáticamente...

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
</service>

<receiver android:name=".BootBroadcast">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Y por ultimo queda iniciar el `servicio` desde nuestro MainActivity:

```
if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)){ //método que determina si el servicio ya está corriendo o no
    serv = new Intent(context,MyService.class); //serv de tipo Intent
    context.startService(serv); // tipo Context
    Log.d("App", "Service started");
} else {
    Log.d("App", "Service already running");
}
```

En caso de que estas ultimas lineas te causen problemas simplemente inicias el servicio de una manera sencilla primero para probar su funcionamiento, con:

```
startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
```

En el `OnCreate`...

IMPORTANTE!!!

Colocar el `permiso` correspondiente para que levante el `servicio` al encender el smarphone...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho este código me viene